# MYSQL RIGHT JOIN not working

Tags: mysql, join

I need to create a report based on two tables. Table one (ka_registrationlog) contains a log of all actions performed by users in the application.
Table two (lara_teacherclass) contains records that connect teachers with their classes per day and hour.
Both tables reside in the same database:

```
SELECT RegDate,
       ka_registrationlog.TeacherID,
       lara_teacherclass.TeacherID,
       lara_teacherclass.ClassID, 
       RegHourID,
       lara_teacherclass.DayOfWeek,
       lara_teacherclass.HourID
  FROM lara_teacherclass LEFT JOIN ka_registrationlog ON 
       lara_teacherclass.TeacherID = ka_registrationlog.TeacherID
   AND lara_teacherclass.HourID = ka_registrationlog.RegHourID
   AND (WEEKDAY(RegDate)+1) = lara_teacherclass.DayOfWeek
 WHERE lara_teacherclass.ClassID = 89
   AND WEEK(RegDate) = WEEK('2015/01/05')
   AND (Type = 1 OR Type = 2)
```

I have tried both LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and Join with either of the tables to the left and each time I end up with 41 records (the number of records in table one while in table two I have 44 records for the given class (89).

Problem is I need to be able to report on those hours/days that no registration was perfomed and I was hoping to d othis with one single query instead of writing a function that would loop through table two and then check if corresponding records could be found in table two (which could lead up to over 50 queries per class (with 100+ classes to loop through).

I've also tried to move the WHERE clause to te ON clause but that yielded no records.

Anyone any idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: If either RegDate or Type is other than what you have in your WHERE clause for the records you require then it may be you need to place those clauses in the JOIN instead.

Comment: in which table are the columns `RegDate` and `Type`? If they are on the "outer" table a `where` condition on them will turn your outer join into an inner join. Move them into the join condition

Comment: You refer to hours/days to loop through.  Can you provide some sample data (edit your original question, use spaces, not tabs between data).  Also, for the hours... is it a finite time period, such as 8am-9pm vs 24-hours, and appears you want every day within the week, thus all hours (per example range) too, correct?